# Was I fired before my resignation date?

Tags: workplace

I submitted my letter of resignation and two-week notice today, and within minutes all my company access was revoked (security privileges, domain access, email access, dropbox, etc.). We work entirely remotely right now, which means I cannot work at all for the remainder of my time. My boss insists I was not fired, but having no ability to work whatsoever it certainly feels like I was. If I was fired I am entitled to severance pay, and I am curious as to what legal basis I may have.

Company is registered in Hong Kong working in multiple countries, I'm assuming the jurisdiction comes from the country where it is registered? If not, I'm not sure, as I (prior to the COVID-19 situation) traveled and worked in all of the countries we were involved in.

Irrelevant to the above question, but relevant to the work situation - I am behind one month's pay and a guaranteed salary increase of "3.5-10%, at the employer's discretion" starting from January that I never received.

Comment: Only your boss knows the answer to this.  But what you experienced sounds pretty common - during your notice period, you're still employed, but your employer chooses not to have you do any work.  If you like, your assigned duties are now to do nothing at all.  That's a business decision they're typically entitled to make, and they commonly do it this way to reduce the chances of disgruntled employees causing trouble on their way out.

Comment: We can't tell you anything about applicable laws until you say what jurisdiction you are in (country, state, etc).

Comment: @NateEldredge Edited the post on jurisdiction, not sure if that helps though. As for your longer comment, that certainly makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: See also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/75936/why-would-a-resigning-employee-be-immediately-escorted-out

Comment: "guaranteed" + "at the employers discretion" == "not guaranteed".

Comment: the "at the employer's discretion" clause refers to how much the raise is (within the guaranteed bounds of 3.5-10%, later clarified in the same document as coming from your annual performance review).